# HTTP / HTTPS connections very slow in Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I'm using Docker for Mac v 1.12.3, the problem I am having is that that HTTP and HTTPS connections are very slow. DNS and Ping seem fine but HTTP(S) takes for example 5 seconds on the docker image but 0.05 seconds on the host:

```
Host (MacOS Sierra):
time curl www.google.com
0.05 real 
0.00 user 
0.00 sys

Docker:
time curl www.google.com
real 0m5.615s
user 0m0.010s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I can't see any reason for this or any other people with the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding a valid nameserver to the top of the list in /etc/resolv.conf seems to have fixed it for me. Not sure why a valid DNS is not in this list. Still trying to see if one can be passed to Docker for Mac or HyperKit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that */etc/resolv.conf* had 10 different nameserver entries (similar to 192.168.65.1). Adding Google's DNS before any of those got rid of all the lag.

**UPDATE:**
You might find (as I did) that the change via the moby debian host (below), doesn't actually persist across restarts. I found that v1.12.3 of Docker for Mac does now, however, respect both the `--dns` flag for the `run` command, as well as the `dns` property in a compose file. If you use the `--dns` flag, you don't need to modify any *resolv.conf* with the flag, it will override all the `nameserver` entries for you.

Doing further digging revealed that I needed to login to the *moby* image to modify the defaults. You can confirm this by looking at the resolv.conf of any of the images you've built. If they don't have a known-DNS, then you need to follow the directions here:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24344#issuecomment-239942428

Comment: that did it! I also had to remove the invalid entries from the list leaving only Google's DNS in resolve.conf! many thanks!

Comment: @user1167223 Added an edit upon further testing.

Comment: Yup, just noticed the same thing, after restart the DNS went back, using the `--dns` flag is def the way to go I think. Many thanks again

Comment: Thanks so much! Using `--dns 8.8.8.8` took the `friendlyhello` example from [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2) from 2.5 MINUTES to 0.1 seconds.